# Mathematical Modeling and Statistical Modeling

Tags: self-study, references, stochastic-processes, model, terminology

What is the difference between mathematical modeling and statistical modeling?

I only know that a mathematical model is deterministic while a statistical model is stochastic.

Is that all to answer the question?

Comment: I'm not so sure there is a difference. The terms are used interchangeably.

Comment: The difference is what @tree said. One is deterministic and one is stochastic. If someone use them  interchangeably, in my opinion he is wrong

Comment: If anyone wanted to define mathematical modelling to include statistical modelling as a special case, that's fine by me. It's perhaps more common to define statistical modelling in contrast to statistical modelling. But quite where to draw the line is difficult, yet also not important, except for administrators, librarians and other people obliged to do so as part of their duties. Work on stochastic differential equations can straddle any boundary, for example.

Comment: @NickCox the line would probably best be drawn at the incorporation of uncertainty. Purely "mathematical" models do not incorporate uncertainty; "probabilistic" models incorporate fundamental uncertainty in a data-generating process; "statistical" models incorporate uncertainty induced by sampling from a population.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Good luck in sustaining that probabilistic/statistical distinction with colleagues and students, as few will promise to echo your personal division! Where do stochastic differential equations lie? More crucially, where would you place "exploratory data analysis" in Tukey's sense?

Comment: @NickCox I don't subscribe to it myself, it just seems like what most people have in mind when they use those terms. But by that criterion I'd say stochastic diff eq. are a fundamentally "probabilistic" model, and it's what I'd call them anyway.

Comment: I'd also say stochastic differential equations are probabilistic models, and know e.g. quant finance friends think of themselves as probabilists, and not statisticians , for various reasons.  I agree the distinction is very blurry.

Comment: @Nick How would you classify e.g. spin glass models or random permutation representations of quantum spin models?  They are most certainly not deterministic.  I think we can agree they are not "statistical", either?

Comment: Returning to SDEs: there is a lot of work e.g. on inference for the parameters etc.  I'd classify that as more statistical.

Comment: I think we can agree that often different people want to distinguish between probabilistic and statistical. So far so good, but a small issue is that I doubt that people would draw the line in the same place. Emphasis on "small". This can be a matter of community not content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind, statistical modelling is a special case of probabilistic modelling, which is a special case of mathematical modelling.. but I don't usually bother to distinguish them and think often the difference is more of cultures.  Things I associate more with statistical modelling are replication, the special role of intuition, and data exploration.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. $\text{statistical} \subset \text{mathematical}$. Although I wonder if there are some statistical models that one could argue are non-probabilistic (although it seems there is always a probabilistic _interpretation_ even when models are not intended to be probabilistic).

Comment: What about alternative ways to model "uncertainty", in some sense? Fuzzy sets, DEmpster-Shafer theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory  ...

Comment: hi @kjetilbhalvorsen, I don't know about Dempster-Shafer theory but after an extra 2.5 years of hands on modelling experience my views have been refined and I hope to revise my answer above accordingly soon :)

Answer (score -1):

What is the difference between mathematics and statistics? !

Statistics is itself a branch of mathematics where most of the time we deal with mean, median, mode etc, although they require mathematical computation as well.

Same way in machine learning statistical models has most of the computation related to mean, median, quantiles etc. Ex- Linear Regression, Logistic Regression.

Comment: I don't agree that statistics is a branch of mathematics. Mathematics provides tools for statistics.

Comment: If anyone knows maths of universe he must be knowing statistics, that's why statistics is branch of maths